# Greater than and less than together

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I would like to overloading operator > in c++ to be possible write codes like this:

```
if(a>x>b)...;
```

I have seen that this operator requires just two arguments.

Any idea how to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: wow, why can't I dream with a better world lol...I dreamed and just get a minus 1...

Comment: @MooingDuck Why don't do this. I believe that it must be like math operations. Before any language it is used in math and operations like this are possible.
It would be wonderful if we could declare x: 5 < x < 10; Could you image how incredible and useful it could be...

Comment: Basically, C++ is not designed to do that, though a future arbitrary language could be.  In C++ the real problem is, what does `10<x<5` mean?

Comment: @MooingDuck I see your question. Ok, C++ is not designed to do this, but I'm just kidding with the language. I see that even with the answer before it's not exactly what I'd like. I'd like in fact a language more math alike that could give the expressiveness of the mathematics.

Comment: C++ can express more than "mathematics" can, it's merely a different syntax.

Comment: Within mathematics scope, I have to disagree.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a relatively simple example but it should do what you want:

```
#include <iostream>

struct cool_operator
{
    cool_operator(int _n = 0, bool b = true) : first(b), n(_n) {}

    bool first;

    bool operator <(int x) const
    {
        return first && (n < x);
    }

    int n;
};

cool_operator operator <(int x, cool_operator const &rhs)
{
    return cool_operator(lhs.n, x < rhs.n);
}

int main()
{
    cool_operator c(4);

    std::cout << std::boolalpha << (3 < c < 5); // true
}
```

**[Here is a demo.](http://ideone.com/MqLdif#view_edit_box)**

To make this complete, you should add member function overloads for the greater than operator, and implement the free function overload version of it too.

Comment: If you're going to go to all that trouble, you might as well just write a `between` function.

Comment: I know that there is this way to do this. But, why not kidding with the language.

Comment: This code have two problems, first, n is static and should not be initialized in the constructor, and second, try this with 8 rather than 4.

Comment: @Leandro Where did you get the idea that `n` is `static`? It's a normal variable. And I tried with 8 and it works.

Comment: well, maybe Cygwin doesn't like this kidding! See:

..\src\CppTestes.cpp:16:13: error: ISO C++ forbids initialization of member 'n' [-fpermissive]
..\src\CppTestes.cpp:16:13: error: making 'n' static [-fpermissive]
..\src\CppTestes.cpp:16:13: error: ISO C++ forbids in-class initialization of non-const static member 'n'
..\src\CppTestes.cpp: In constructor 'cool_operator::cool_operator(int)':
..\src\CppTestes.cpp:6:29: error: 'int cool_operator::n' is a static data member; it can only be initialized at its definition

Comment: @Leandro Well now I see that your compiler doesn't support C++11. The problem is that you're not using the latest update I made to my code. Copy and paste the code I have here and try again.

Comment: I believe that it is making it static because it's initialized in the scope of the struct.

Comment: @Leandro If you still get errors, replace `= default` with `{}` (another C++11 feature).

Comment: @Leandro Please let me know if it's working for you. I want to help as much as I can.

Comment: Great, thanks! It's working now! even with = default